# Why won't this div close when I click on the link which opens it?

Tags: jquery

[Here's the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/rowbuck/gT5BT/97/)

The code includes:

```
$('.icon').click(function () {
    $('.foo').toggle();
});
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $('.foo');

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
    &&
    container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

I can use the link to open it, the codes closes it when one clicks outside of it but I can't close it with the link that opened it initially.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gT5BT/104/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the check in your if statement to see if `.icon` is the target.

http://jsfiddle.net/gT5BT/100/

```
var foo = $('.foo'), icon = $('.icon');

icon.click(function () {
    foo.toggle();
});

$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    if (!foo.is(e.target) && !icon.is(e.target) && !foo.has(e.target).length)
        foo.hide();
});
```

Comment: Precisely. Just was ready to post my own fix which addressed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You hiding and showing it again. Just comment `container.hide();` and try clicking `.icon`

To overcome this issue just check for `.icon` container in global `mouseup` event handler. http://jsfiddle.net/55DSp/

Comment: No, that doesn't work because it cannot be closed by clicking outside and limits the close to .icon.

Comment: Thanks anyway but not a solution.

Comment: Yeah, myself, Wex, and you all concluded same at about the same time.  Thanks for helping out.